# Spring 3.2 using security : error URLPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(Z)V while deploying

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on a spring-mvc project in `3.1`(spring version : 3.1.2.RELEASE and security 3.1.3.RELEASE)
I'm trying to move into `3.2` latests release `3.2.17 (spring)` and `3.2.9` for spring security, following http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html (but i don't really get what D6 part means : what i have to change?)

I modified the pom and the schema `(3.2.xsd)`. But while deploying the war into my glassfish server I get this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(Z)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
```

I don't get it as in my war the following class exists with the correct method in `spring-web-3.2.17.RELEASE.jar` to be accurate.

Do you have any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Did you do 'mvn package' and look into war contents?

Comment: Yes i did, and the war built contains the class with the method (jar spring-web-3.2.17.RELEASE.jar included)

Comment: Double-check that you don't have an old jar left somewhere in classpath.